# How to install Qt5 libraries for Windows 10 for cmake development?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cmake

I want to develop in Windows 10 with cmake. I don't need QtCreator, nor any other things. Just the minimum to compile with cmake. I downloaded the qt online installed and selected Qt 5.14.1 but it has 36gb! I don't even have that amount of space.

What is the bare minimum to run Qt/QML applications with cmake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I downloaded the qt online installed and selected Qt 5.14.1 but it has 36gb!

There are many different builds of Qt 5.14.1 (one build for MSVC 2017 32-bit, one build for MSVC 2017 64-bit, one build for MinGW 7.3.0 32-bit, one build for MinGW 7.3.0 64-bit, one build for Android, and so on)

If you select "Qt 5.14.1", you select *all* the builds. That's why you're seeing 36 GB.

Instead of selecting "Qt 5.14.1," expand it and select a single build that matches your compiler. The libraries for MSVC 2017 32-bit is less than 600 MB:

[image: Qt installer component selection]

> What is the bare minimum to run Qt/QML applications with cmake?

The *easiest* way to get started is to use the Qt installer. You just need to select 2 components:

1. **Qt > Qt 5.14.1 > *(One build of your choice)***
2. **Qt > Developer and Designer Tools > Qt Creator 4.11.1**

Note 1: You need a C++ compiler, and this compiler must match the build that you choose. Either install the MSVC compiler from Microsoft, or choose **Qt > Developer and Designer Tools > MinGW 7.3.0 xx-bit**

Note 2: You can't de-select Qt Creator in the installer, but that's <600 MB.

If you really, really want to avoid installing Qt Creator, then you must build the Qt libraries from source code. Here are the instructions: https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git